# Makefile, clang OK, gcc error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, clang

I have makefile which works with clang and fail with gcc, when I comment/uncoment clang/gcc ... I don't know why.

```
#CC=gcc
#CFLAGS=-I -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic

CC=clang
CFLAGS=-I -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic

LIBS=-lpthread -lrt

SRC=rivercrossing.c functions.c
OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)
DEPS=rivercrossing.h

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

rivercrossing: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o rivercrossing
```

With gcc I have following errors:

```
error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]
           int stat = 0;
           ^

error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90 [-Werror]
```

Also *.o files are not deleted, when I look to the folder they are still there. Why?
Thank you for you help.

Comment: You need to pass `CFLAGS` while creating the object files.

Comment: Try changing `$(CC) -c -o $@ $<` to `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<`

Comment: It didn't help, gcc -c -I -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o functions.o functions.c and same error like before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use C99 mode instead of gnu99 mode or you can declare variable outside of for loop.

There is a compiler switch which enables C99 mode, which amongst other things allows declaration of a variable inside the for loop. To turn it on use the compiler switch -std=c99